# How do I show a message for a specific dropdown selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I would like to show a message when someone makes a specific selection from an HTML dropdown list. I have this so far:

```
<select name="configoption[56]" onchange="recalctotals()">
<option value="235"">USA</option>
<option value="206">Europe</option>
</select>

<span class="message">You selected USA!</span>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#configoption[56]').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $('#configoption[56]').find(":selected").text();
        if ( selectedValue == '235' ) {
            $('.message').show();
        } else {
            $('.message').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The above does not appear to be working for me, any suggestions? I would also like to be able to show the message on multiple selected values.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#configoption[56]')` is looking for an element with the **`id`**, not **`name`**, `configoption[56]` (or it would be, but the selector is invalid, you'd have to escape those brackets).

To use the name:

```
$('select[name="configoption[56]"]')...
```

Separately, you can just use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val), you don't have to use `find` to get the selected option. You can also use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) for show/hide:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="configoption[56]"]').change(function() {
        $('.message').toggle($(this).val() == '235');
    });
});
```

---

Re your comment about toggling based on `||` and two values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="configoption[56]"]').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.message').toggle(value == '235' || value == '123');
    });
});
```

Comment: This also seems to work well. I like the toggle animation. Is there a way I can toggle on for two vals? I added || and another val but it just toggles on and off.

Comment: @Conserta: `toggle` isn't an animation. Yes, you can use multiple values, the rules are identical to those for `if`: `if (value == x || value == y)`. It sounds like you just didn't have the `||` in the right place. (If you're going to check for multiple values, I'd store the result of `$(this).val()` in a variable.)

Comment: @Conserta: I've added an example.

Comment: That did it T.J. thank you so much it works perfectly. It's great that I don't have to add an id with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well your `.change` function is specifically binded to an element with `id="configoption[56]"` So just add id to your `select` element as below

```
<select name="configoption[56]"  id="configoption[56]" onchange="recalctotals()">
   //Options
</select>
```

---

**UPDATE**

As per @T.J.Crowder's suggestion on invalid `selector` I would like to modify a slight change on the `id`. You can use `configoption56` as id and write your `select.change` as follows:

```
<select name="configoption[56]"  id="configoption56" onchange="recalctotals()">
       <!--Options-->
</select>
```

`.change`

```
$('#configoption56').change(function() {
  //other codes
});
```

Comment: The selector `#configoption[56]` is [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (it would need escaping). The current jQuery *might* let it work (it allows some other invalid `id` selectors if they're on their own), but it may not (you'd have to check), and there's no guarantee that if it does *now* the next dot release won't break it, because (again) it's invalid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Sorry for that but can you please let me know how?

Comment: You can't use unescaped `[` or `]` in `id` selectors. (Note I said "`id` selectors", not `id`s. They're perfectly valid in `id`s.) The escaped version is really hard to read: `#configoption\5b56\5d` and even harder to write in a string literal: `"#configoption\\5b56\\5d"`.

Answer (score 0):

I should be doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nmn17cr6/

HTML:

```
<select name="configoption[56]" id="configoption" onchange="recalctotals()">
<option value="1">Dummy</option>
<option value="235">USA</option>
<option value="206">Europe</option>
</select>
<span class="message">You selected USA!</span>
```

CSS:

```
.message {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#configoption').change(function() {

        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        if ( selectedValue == '235' ) {
            $('.message').show();
        } else {
            $('.message').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This seem to work well, thank you, I would like to add multiple values to show the message. I tried if ( selectedValue == '235' && '202' ) but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I figured it out || duh! Thank you for an awesome answer! I can't vote yet :(

Comment: I spoke a little too soon the || seems to disable the message from hiding when a different option is selected. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: did you do something like this?  `if ( selectedValue == '235' || selectedValue == '202') {`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach needs a little modification. All you had to do these changes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select[name=configoption[56]]").change(function() { // change jquery selector for name
    var selectedValue = $('#configoption[56]').val(); // and val to get the value
    if ( selectedValue == '235' ) {
        $('.message').show();
    } else {
        $('.message').hide();
    }
});
});
```

And with the same `jQuery` code. below has to be

```
  <select name="configoption[56]" >
  // onchange="recalctotals()"> was not required
```